# Unable to ARD to remote machine

Tags: network, macos, ssh, remote-desktop

I've set up a computer on another subnet.  This machine is on ip 10.1.1.39.  I am able to ssh to it and the prompt returns the correct name for the machine.

When I try to ARD, it fails to connect.  I check on the remote computer and it had remote management set.  When I check using `sudo tcpdump -n -i any src or dst my.current.pc.ip` I see a LOT of traffic.

When I try to `telnet 10.1.1.39 5900` I get the following response:
RFB 003.889

Is there something simple I am missing?

Note:

Both machines are on 10.12.6 (Sierra).  Both are on different subnets, but can see one another with ping and ssh.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you have to enable port forwarding 5900 on the subnet you are attempting to access. Possibly other ports as well. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944

Comment: The firewall between subnets is set to allow IP access (hence I can telnet to the port).  Port forwarding shouldn't be needed, and I have other machines in the same subnet I can ARD to.

Comment: As a test, does it work on the same subnet?